# Using Outlook interop, how can I save an attached .msg that's open in Inspector?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-interop

I'm working on an Outlook add-in button that saves the active mail item to the filesystem.

It works fine except on `.msg` attachments:

[image: An email open in Outlook with a file named "message.msg" attached to it; the attachment is itself an email]

When the user double-clicks `message.msg`, a new Outlook inspector window opens, showing that email.

Next, the user clicks my add-in button to save that email to the filesystem. At this point, an exception is thrown:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation.'

How can I save an attached email to the filesystem from an Inspector window?

Comment: Which lien of your code raises that exception?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko `mailItem.SaveAs`. It works on a copy (same filesystem path).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Use `mailItem.Copy().SaveAs()`.

The problem is that the attached email is read-only. For some reason, interop forbids calling `SaveAs` on read-only emails.

If you call `Copy()`, the new instance of the mail item is not read-only and can be saved to the disk without issue.

> Note: Before copying the mail item, check whether it's truly read-only, because copying can be slow depending on the mail item's size. Use `GetProperty` to determine this; `MailItem` unfortunately doesn't have a `ReadOnly` property built in.

```
bool isMailItemReadOnly = mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF70003") == 0;
string path = @"C:\MyFolder\message.msg";

if (isMailItemReadOnly)
{
    mailItem.Copy().SaveAs(path);
}
else
{
    mailItem.SaveAs(path);
}
```